# Change language of RabbitVCS context menu

Tags: svn, rabbitvcs

How do I change the language of the RabbitVCS context menu to english? (mine is currently german) The settings dialog has no option for this.

.config/rabbitvcs/settings.conf has a language option, but setting this to “en_US” does not show any effect.

(RabbitVCS 0.15.2 on Linux Mint 17.1)

Answer (score 2):

First, check in **.config/rabbitvcs/settings.conf** to confirm what is your language. Mine was:

```
[general]
    language = en_US
    enable_attributes = True
    enable_emblems = True
    enable_recursive = True
    show_debug = False
(...)
```

Then check under /usr/share/locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/ to confirm there is no RabbitVCS file. In my case, I just copied the en_GB version:

```
sudo cp /usr/share/locale/en_GB/LC_MESSAGES/RabbitVCS.mo /usr/share/locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/RabbitVCS.mo
```

Then restart nautilus with:

```
nautilus -q
```

Hope this helps.

update for Ubuntu 20.04: I've recently updated my Ubuntu and this fix  stopped working. As a workaround, I've just removed the RabbitVCS.mo corresponding to my language in:

/usr/share/locale/pt_BR/LC_MESSAGES/RabbitVCS.mo

Comment: It's not the best way but fixed my problem with context menu in pt_BR. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is no language option in the settings page, though
you could theoretically force it to use English if you were willing to
edit some python code.

To force English as the only language, edit your installed
/rabbitvcs/__ init __.py (should be in your python/site-packages folder
somewhere. In my case /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rabbitvcs), and on line 42, add:

```
langs = ["en_US"]
```

or

```
langs = ["en_GB"]
```

which will overwrite the auto-configured language.

To see more details, 
access [google groups issue](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rabbitvcs/hOvlrZTyz6M) associated